# Navigation Bar with prompt in UIpopover

Tags: iphone, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a navigation Controller as the view of a popover, so that there is a navigation bar at the top.

On the first view there is no prompt for the navigation bar, so it remains at it's usual small size.

I then push the next view controller which does need a prompt and the bar expands, except behind the view, hiding the Title and Back button.

If I comment out the code in loadView, so that self.view is never set, then you can see the backbutton and title, but you can't click on the back button, as if it was behind another view.

I never had this problem in 3.2, only now in 4.2

Comment: How is the popover being sized?

Answer (score 0):

Here you can set the size of popover using the following code:

```
self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320, 460);
```

You need to set the content size of popover in view using this code and you can add this code in the viewdidLoad mehtof of the controller. Let me know if you still have any question.